# What qualifies as a ditransitive verb, really?

Tags: transitivity

The context for this question is that I am preparing an introductory grammar course to be taught to adult Papua New Guineans from different language groups who have varying levels of secondary school education. Actually, I am revising existing materials for the course and I am troubled by the confusing picture the materials paint about transitivity and the very limited examples of ditransitive verbs that are given.

I tried consulting Wikipedia but the Ditransitive Verb page leaves much to be desired. I have consulted various text books and they are not entirely clear on this matter either.

It seems that a common definition of ditransitive verbs only includes those which can use dative shift to allow for two bare NPs as objects of the verb. This limited list includes, of course, *give*, and also verbs like *tell (someone a story)*, *show (someone a picture)*. Even verbs like *bake (someone a cake)*, and *read (someone a book)*, are included even though the beneficiaries of the reading and baking seem only loosely connected, semantically. In English this 'restricted definition' of ditransitive verbs seems to only allow recipients and in some cases beneficiaries.

But why such a restricted list? In my thinking, if the verb needs three arguments to feel complete, then it should count as a ditransitive (trivalent) verb. Why are verbs that take PPs, gerunds, infinitive phrases, adjectives, complement clauses, quoted speech, etc. as arguments excluded? Here are some examples:

1. She put the keys in the drawer. (*She put the keys.)
2. The guards prevented the man from escaping. (*The guards prevented the man.)
3. That makes me uncomfortable. (*That makes me. — an adjective is not a typical object.)
4. The judge sentenced Billy to 2 years in prison.
5. Bob drove the truck to Arizona. (Both "the truck" and "to Arizona" are omittable, but still)
6. Momma told me not to come. (Again, just "Momma told me" is grammatical, but the infinitive phrase seems to be very much an argument of *tell*.)
7. He told us "This is the way." (A variant of #6.)
8. He told us (that) this is the way. (A variant of #7.)
9. I bet Dave $50 that the Cubs would win. (actually tritransitive)

I could go on, but you probably get the idea. Each of the verbs takes three arguments. Either it is ungrammatical to remove any of the arguments, or they just seem to be too closely associated to the verb, according to my intuition, not to be called an argument. This issue also applies to (what I would call) transitive verbs which don't take a prototypical object, such as *say* [quote or complement clause], *go* [PP goal], *seem* [adjective], *know* [complement/WH clause], and *enjoy* [gerund phrase].

I know what an adjunct is. These verbs in question are different from something like "I work out [at the gym on third street, on Mondays and Fridays, from 7 to 9]". *Work out* is an intransitive verb and everything in the square brackets there is peripheral information.

I am prepared to accept that some transitivity is more transitive than other transitivity. I can see how you could have various tests for transitivity or "true argument status" and some verbs/arguments might pass all the tests while others only partially do. For example, allowing dative shift and allowing the argument to be the subject of a passive clause would be strong evidence for transitivity. Surely if the clause sounds broken without the argument, that is another piece of evidence. Presumably tests could be constructed that even let the GOAL of a movement verb be considered a true argument.

I need to know what I can safely teach these students. I have a hard time telling them that only verbs like *give* and *show* can be called ditransitive, but is this the standard view out there? I am having trouble proving otherwise. One textbook I read (Analyzing Grammar, Paul Kroeger) talks about oblique arguments being real arguments of the verb, but it didn't give any definition of what constitutes a ditransitive verb.

Comment: I'd define it as 'A verb that licenses two objects, indirect and direct', e.g. "gave" in "Ed gave me the key", (i.e. S-P-Oi-Od).  In your example "She put the keys in the drawer", the PP "in the drawer" is obligatory and hence is a complement, more specifically a non-core complement.

Comment: According to the definition I'd use, a ditransitive verb has three arguments. So I'd basically agree with you, except not for your example 5, where "to Arizona" is just an adjunct.

Comment: Why quarrel about definitions?  Giving definitions is not doing grammar.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'd say that the PP "to Arizona" is not an adjunct but a complement, since it has to be licensed by the head "drive", i.e. a verb of motion.

Comment: @BillJ Then would you say "from Alaska" and "by the expressway" would also be complements? Where does it end?

Comment: @curiousdannii It would end right there. Drive, and many motion verbs license a goal, a source and/or a path. Of course how those semantic roles are expressed can involve many different prepositions in English.

Comment: I would call anything licensed by the verb (besides the subject) a complement, including direct and indirect objects. If the complement is a NP hiding behind a preposition I would call it an oblique argument. If it is a gerund or WH clause or something else, I guess I have no other special terms for those. I want to quarrel about definitions because I have to teach these students SOMETHING and I want to teach them concepts that will be useful using terms that won't confuse them and linguists that they speak with, down the road.

Comment: @Moss Through the tunnel? On the left side of the road? If anything specific to "drive" is a complement then it will end up licensing a dozen different complements.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, they would be locative complements, 'source' and 'path' respectively.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have developed a random sentence generator (http://tr.im/sengen) as a way to sharpen my understanding of grammar. For ground-bound motion verbs such as 'drive' I have 21 possible PP complements, such as through, across, into, from, under, along and so on. I am sure there could be some more I left out. In fact I didn't consider 'on' as a potential path complement. That one seems a bit ambiguous to me. Anyway, all this variety is thanks to English's rich system of prepositions.

Comment: @Moss  I don't know why you think that "I bet Dave $50 that the Cubs would win" is tritransitive. It's ditransitive - English has only two kinds of object, direct and indirect.

Comment: @BillJ Because *bet*, and *trade* and probably a few other such verbs can take 4 arguments. I don't think numbers of object is really a significant factor compared to number of arguments/complements but apparently other linguists do. That is the whole point of my question.

Comment: @Moss  I think you're confusing transitivity with valency. "I bet Dave $50 that the Cubs would win" is ditransitive and quadrivalent. Transitivity refers specifically to objects while Valency is used for the number of complements.

Comment: @BillJ "Valency is used for the number of complements" - usually **valency is used for the number of arguments**, complements being only one subset of arguments.

Comment: I disagree. Valency **is** used for the number of complements.

Comment: @BillJ That is you right of course. That being said, this is **not** how valency is usually understood in syntax. I wonder if 1. you make any distinction between an argument and a complement; 2. What you call subjects, complements or arguments etc.